# Defining neighborhood settings in Focal Statistics with Calculate Value using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, parameters, focal-statistics

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 with Spatial Analyst.

I use ModelBuilder, and I created a model with focal statistic. There are 2 different workflows now.

1. calculate the radius value: This value depends on the vertex distance of input- I get this number using with Calculate Value tool
2. run focal statistic - Neighborhood settings: circle, map unit, where Radius would be equal the calculated value
   Now I have to run the first part of the model, than I have to type in the number manually.

Is there any way to use this number automaticly without typing?

Comment: If you use ArcGIS Pro, you can do the following - in your calculate value tool, set the datatype to neighborhood and return a string like `"Circle 7 MAP"` (where 7 is the radius you calculated) and just connect it to the focal statistics tool as the neighborhood parameter, but I couldn't get this to work in ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap).